# HTML <a name="#ref> tag with spacer before

Tags: html, tags, toolbar, space

I have a page with a fixed toolbar on top which is always visible no matter where the user scrolls vertically on the page. That toolbar is about 40px high.

I also have a table of contents on that page that uses `<a href="#ref>` tags to point to specific portions of the page. Of course, there are also `<a id="ref>` tags to mark where those portions are.

My problem is that the toolbar I have on the page (which is fixed on top) obstructs the first two or three lines of the portion of text where `#ref` links to. Is there any way to add a spacer to (or before) the `a` tag so that no space is actually seen between the lines, but when the user clicks on the link, the page is scrolled a bit less and the text isn't blocked?

Comment: `<a name="#ref>` should be `<a name="ref">` actually it should be `<a id="ref">` since we're in 2013

Comment: you're right, of course. I mistyped it

Comment: Actually you should simply use `id` on the section or the heading and throw the additional `a` tag away.

Comment: Oh, nice one. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:target {
     display:block;
     padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This will change the targeted element's behaviour into a block and apply a padding. Note that `display:block` isn't necessary if you use `id` only on block-level elements ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ZMv/)).

Also note that this will definitely not work if you link to a word in the middle of a sentence. In this case you will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: That does the trick wonderfully. However, the highlight animation doesn't seem to be working for me... I don't see any yellow background.

Comment: @Alex: Probably a webkit based browser? You need to add `-webkit` and `-ms`, Firefox doesn't need prefixes anymore.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Safari. I changed it to `-webkit-animation-duration` and `-webkit-animation-name` but I still don't see anything.

Comment: @Alex: `@-webkit-keyframes`. But honestly, this was my first animation ever and just an additional extra :D.

Comment: Extra or not it is actually a great idea. Also you forgot the name of the animation had to be enclosed in `'`. With those corrections it does animate, but only the area we added for the padding! Everything else stays white. I've checked and there's no other background color defined anywhere that would be on top of the yellow...

Comment: Actually, if I delete the `h3` tag I have right after `<p id="ref">` it does animate the text inside the `<p>`. If I keep the `h3` it only animates those 40px on top.

Comment: @Alex: Well, honestly, I don't know your code structure and I'm not used to animations at all. Maybe it would be a good idea to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)? However, check whether your document is valid first and whether structure actually makes sense. Note that `h3` inside of an `p` is not allowed by both logic (a heading is not inside of a paragraph) and [standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-p-element.html).

Comment: So, I ended up giving up on the animation idea and used this: `:target { padding-top: 50px; margin-top: -50px; }` The `-50px` margin means the user sees no space at all between lines, but the `50px` padding means a space is there when the browser scrolls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25909/discussion-between-zeta-and-alex)

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-top` to the `body` element that is equal to the height of your toolbar (40px)